# Firestore doesn't save updated data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

```
export class Register extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: "",
      CaloricGoal: 0,
    };
    this.onSignUp = this.onSignUp.bind(this);
  }

    onSignUp() {
        var {
          email,
          CaloricGoal,
        } = this.state;
        firebase
          .auth()
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then((result) => {
            firebase
              .firestore()
              .collection("users")
              .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
              .set({
                email,
                CaloricGoal,
    
              });
            console.log(result);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
 render() {

var CaloricGoal =
      selectedGoal === 1
        ? (TDEE * details + TDEE).toFixed(0)
        : selectedGoal == 2
        ? (TDEE - caloricDeficit).toFixed(0)
        : TDEE.toFixed(0);

return (
      <SafeAreaView
        style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white", alignItems: "center" }}
      >

 <TextInput
                style={styles.inputEmail}
                label="email"
                placeholder="Email Address"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCompleteType="none"
                autoCorrect="false"
                keyboardType="email-address"
                onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
              />
```

So I'm trying to save `email` and `CaloricGoal` in my firestore document, but `email` is the only one that saves, `CaloricGoal` will remain 0, I believe it's because after I insert the values of the function and get the result, the state doesn't update itself so It just returns 0, how can I fix that?

Comment: Check, when you log the value of CaloricaGoal inside onSignUp() function you get the correct value

Comment: yes, I get the correct value, how can I fix this?

Comment: So you get correct value for CaloricaGoal (1 or 2) inside onSignUp function, but the firestore document still has CaloricaGoal as 0?

Comment: when I insert the values of the variables, the correct result shows on the page, but it doesn't upload it on the firestore document

Comment: Where are you getting CaloricaGoal from? Because in the state it's always 0? You get selected goal when goal is selected update caloricagoal in state

Comment: I get the value by various text inputs that fill the variables in the formula for CaloricGoal

Comment: @PiersalvoMigliore Could you share the CaloricGoal input code?